# How to change the display language in "Movie Maker"?

Tags: windows, display, language, windows-movie-maker, english

I am currently using Windows XP Chinese version on my computer. I am using Movie Maker, but it's all in Chinese. Is there any possible way for me to "make it look" English without the need of installing English Windows XP? Perhaps, it is possible to install the English version of Movie Maker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure if this will work, but you could try changing the language of Windows. Its in Control Panel and under Region and Language.

As I said, im not sure if this will change the language in Movie Maker too, but its worth a try.

Comment: I think his question is about changing just Movie Makers language to English without changing the entire OS language or installing another language pack. What you suggest would require english be installed and would change everything to english.

Comment: Yeah I know, but just for occasional use it could be ok. I dont know of any other way to change the language. If he reinstalled Movie maker selecting English when installing (if it even give you that option), he would have to re-install every time to change language which is a whole lot more hassle. I am happy to stand corrected should anyone have a better solution.